# Magento Connect no longer works after migration

Tags: magento-connect, migration

I moved a site from a dev server to production and Magento Connect no longer works.  I've seen several posts on the /downloader/perlib fix but I'm using 1.9.1 and that file isn't there.

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer works"?

Comment: It routes to a frontend 404

Comment: Check my answer, you might have some missing files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download a fresh copy of Magento and put the downloader folder in the root of your installation. Is this or bad permissions.